# How to collect data from element after click on button?

Tags: javascript, html, web, button, onclick

I created a simply shop online. I tried to create a script that would retrieve data from an element after click on button "add to basket". Next if user choose and add products to basket then click "Go to Basket". Program should display basket section where there are product informations: Name, price and size. And if there are more than one choosen product program should sum all prices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl" "eng">
    <!---->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Goodclothes</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="bluza_ikona.png">
    <script  defer src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
    </style>
        <body>
        
        <form style="border: 1px solid; background-color: #F5F2E9;" class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;"><i>Goodclothes<i></h1>
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="maint">OUR PRODUCTS</legend>
            <!---->
            <div name="Green hoodie">
            <a 
            onMouseOver='change1.src="green2.jpg"'
            onMouseOut='change1.src="green1.jpg"'>
            <img src="green1.jpg" id="change1" alt="Green hoodie" border="0" width= "212" height= "318">
            </a>
            
            <h4>Green hoodie</h4>
            <p id="price1" value="119,99">Price: 119,99 PLN</p><br>
            <p>Choose size:</p>
            <select id="size1">
            <option value="xs">XS</option>
            <option value="s">S</option>
            <option value="m">M</option>
            <option value="l">L</option>
            <option value="xl">XL</option>
            <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart('Green hoodie', 'price1', 'size1')">ADD TO BASKET </button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        
        
        <fieldset>
            <div>
            <a 
            onMouseOver='change2.src="ablack2.jpg"'
            onMouseOut='change2.src="ablack1.jpg"'>
            
            <img src="ablack1.jpg" id="change2" alt="Black hoodie Asian Style" border="0" width="212" height="318">
            </a>
            
            <h4>Black hoodie asian style</h4>
            <p id="price2" value="139,99">Price: 139,99 PLN</p>
            <p>Choose size:</p>
            <select id="size2">
            <option value="xs">XS</option>
            <option value="s">S</option>
            <option value="m">M</option>
            <option value="l">L</option>
            <option value="xl">XL</option>
            <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart('Black hoodie asian style', 'cena2', 'size2')">ADD TO BASKET</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset> <br>
        
        </form>
        
        <div align="center">
            <button  type="button" class="addToCart" id="bucket" onclick="openBucket()">Go to basket</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id="cart" style="display: none;">
        <h2>BASKET</h2>
        <div id="cartItems"></div>
        <p id="totalPrice"></p>
        </div>
        
        </body>
</html>
```

And script:

```
var cart = [];


function addToCart(name, priceElementId, sizeElementId) {
    var price = document.getElementById(priceElementId)[0].value;
    var size = document.getElementById(sizeElementId).value;
    
    console.log("Adding to basket:", name, price, size);
    
    var product = {
        name: name,
        size: size,
        price: parseFloat(price),
    };
    
    cart.push(product);
    
    console.log("Basket after adding:", cart);
    
    updateCartDisplay();
}

function updateCartDisplay() {
    var cartItemsDiv = document.getElementById("cartItems");
    var totalPriceParagraph = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    
    cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = '';
    
    var totalPrice = cart.reduce(function (sum, product) {
        return sum + product.price;
    }, 0);

    cart.forEach(function (product) {
        var productInfo = document.createElement("p");
        productInfo.textContent = product.name + " - Size: " + product.size + " - Size: " + product.price.toFixed(2) + " PLN";
        cartItemsDiv.appendChild(productInfo);
    });
    totalPriceParagraph.textContent = "Total price: " + totalPrice.toFixed(2) + " PLN";
}

function openBucket() {
    var cartDiv = document.getElementById("cart");
    cartDiv.style.display = "block";
    
    updateCartDisplay();
}
```

Finally after adding product to basket and open basket program displays shopping cart (means nothing) and total price: 0,00. I tried solve it on different ways even with ChatGPT but still have a problem and dont know where.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value attribute to a p element. I added a div where in its innerHTML put the price that I will retrieve later by your code using var price = document.getElementById(priceElementId).innerHTML. You can do it in other ways as well. Otherwise everything else seems working correctly.

```js
var cart = [];


function addToCart(name, priceElementId, sizeElementId) {
    var price = document.getElementById(priceElementId).innerHTML;
    var size = document.getElementById(sizeElementId).value;
    //console.log(price)
   // console.log("Adding to basket:", name, price, size);
    
    var product = {
        name: name,
        size: size,
        price: parseFloat(price),
    };
    
    cart.push(product);
    
    //console.log("Basket after adding:", cart);
    
    updateCartDisplay();
}

function updateCartDisplay() {
    var cartItemsDiv = document.getElementById("cartItems");
    var totalPriceParagraph = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    
    cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = '';
    
    var totalPrice = cart.reduce(function (sum, product) {
        return sum + product.price;
    }, 0);

    cart.forEach(function (product) {
        var productInfo = document.createElement("p");
        productInfo.textContent = product.name + " - Size: " + product.size + " - Size: " + product.price.toFixed(2) + " PLN";
        cartItemsDiv.appendChild(productInfo);
    });
    totalPriceParagraph.textContent = "Total price: " + totalPrice.toFixed(2) + " PLN";
}

function openBucket() {
    var cartDiv = document.getElementById("cart");
    cartDiv.style.display = "block";
    
    updateCartDisplay();
}
```

```html
<form style="border: 1px solid; background-color: #F5F2E9;" class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><i>Goodclothes<i></h1>
    <fieldset>
    <legend class="maint">OUR PRODUCTS</legend>
        <!---->
        <div name="Green hoodie">
        <a 
        onMouseOver='change1.src="green2.jpg"'
        onMouseOut='change1.src="green1.jpg"'>
        <img src="green1.jpg" id="change1" alt="Green hoodie" border="0" width= "212" height= "318">
        </a>
        
        <h4>Green hoodie</h4>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">Price <p id="price1">119,99</p>PLN</div>
        <p>Choose size:</p>
        <select id="size1">
        <option value="xs">XS</option>
        <option value="s">S</option>
        <option value="m">M</option>
        <option value="l">L</option>
        <option value="xl">XL</option>
        <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
        </select>
        <br></br>
        <button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart('Green hoodie', 'price1', 'size1')">ADD TO BASKET </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    
    
    <fieldset>
        <div>
        <a 
        onMouseOver='change2.src="ablack2.jpg"'
        onMouseOut='change2.src="ablack1.jpg"'>
        
        <img src="ablack1.jpg" id="change2" alt="Black hoodie Asian Style" border="0" width="212" height="318">
        </a>
        
        <h4>Black hoodie asian style</h4>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">Price <p id="price2">139,99</p>PLN</div>
        <p>Choose size:</p>
        <select id="size2">
        <option value="xs">XS</option>
        <option value="s">S</option>
        <option value="m">M</option>
        <option value="l">L</option>
        <option value="xl">XL</option>
        <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
        </select>
        <br></br>
        <button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart('Black hoodie asian style', 'price2', 'size2')">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset> <br>
    
    </form>
    
    <div align="center">
        <button  type="button" class="addToCart" id="bucket" onclick="openBucket()">Go to basket</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="cart" style="display: none;">
    <h2>BASKET</h2>
    <div id="cartItems"></div>
    <p id="totalPrice"></p>
    </div>
```